# How can I send data via a FT232R chip /PL2303 to display characters /string on the receiving device?

Tags: android, serial-port, usbserial, medical, ftdi

I am sending data from an android app to a medical device via usb. I am using a FTDI RS232 Cable (which has a FT232RL chip) and I also use a Prolific cable (which has a PL2303 chip). I can send characters / string values over the cables. However my character are either converted to decimal format or octadecimal format (base 8) which is a problem. It is a problem because the device wants to receive only strings / characters.

Note: I cant program the medical device: so I cant convert the data format on the receiving end.

Please do anyone have a suggestion for me?

Comment: What are you using to send the data on the Android end? It would seem that you can simply format the data into what the medical device needs, then send it on. You might post a sample of what you are sending, what you are receiving and what you expect to receive.

Comment: *"However my character are either converted to decimal format or octadecimal format (base 8)"*  -- As already suggested, you should provide some examples and more details.  How are you determining that this "conversion" is taking place on which end?  *"Octadecimal"* sounds more like base 18.  Base 8 is simply called octal, just like base 2 is binary and not bidecimal.

Comment: I followed Preseton suggestion and it worked. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the FTDI library by Ksksue (https://github.com/ksksue/FTDriver) for sending data using to and for from the FTDI RS232 Cable. For the Prolific cable, you can use the PL2303 Android Driver Solution (http://www.prolific.com.tw/US/ShowProduct.aspx?p_id=230&pcid=41). I personally used the FTDI cable for my problem.